# What am I missing from the stacking concept?

Tags: html

I'm getting stuck trying to figure out the [HTML stacking concept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context). From what I've read, putting a div at z-index 2 *ought* to make it display above a div with z-index 1... but [it's not doing that](http://jsfiddle.net/qctH9/).

This code...

```
<style>
body > div { height: 100px; width: 100px; }

#blue {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: auto;
}
#red { z-index: 2; }
</style>

<div id="blue">
    <div>blue</div>
    <div>blue</div>
    <div>blue</div>
    <div>blue</div>
    <div>blue</div>
    <div>blue</div>
    <div>blue</div>
    <div>blue</div>
</div>
<div id="red">red</div>
```

... results in a blue div *above* the red div. Changing blue's z-index to -1 finally puts it behind the red div, but then the scrollbar stops working.

What am I missing?

Comment: `position: relative` makes it's position flow in position with it's neighbors, whereas `position: absolute` makes it flow in position with it's parent (which is `position`ed). So: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/qctH9/1/

Comment: Ah, z-index is included in the relative positioning, then. Why won't scrolling work when the cursor is to the side of the other element, but will work when it's above and below it?

Comment: Can you be more precise? Scrolling is working in my browser when the mouse is on the blue box. Outside, or the overlapping region between red and blue, it won't scroll.

Comment: Not quite sure I follow your description. Take a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/qctH9/2/ `z-index` is only applied if an element has been positioned, as you can see in this fiddle.

Comment: For the curious, here's a great article about `z-index`: http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: @abellina I don't know what combination of settings I had, but it wasn't scrolling when I had the mouse in the area to the right of the red div (but still on the blue div).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mVZ9d/

Two things, you had `script` instead of `style`. I assume that was just a typo while writing your question. You should specify `position:relative` in the red div.

`z-index` only works with elements with position `fixed`, `absolute` or `relative`. Relative works just fine as shown in the fiddle.